# Deixar programa feito em Swing com aparência de Windows

Tags: java, swing

Estou desenvolvendo aplicação com Java Swing, mas as telas não estão ficando com cara de janela de windows. Exemplo de tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria deixar com cara de Windows mesmo, com a barra de título com botão minimizar, maximizar e fechar. Do jeito que está não fica visualmente agradável.

Estou usando NetBeans.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tem como definir isso usando `UIManager#setLookAndFeel` pegando o "estilo" do SO no qual a aplicação está rodando. Mas você quer que sua aplicação tenha "cara de Windows" em todos os sistemas operacionais ou só no Windows mesmo?

Comment: Valew cara, tentarei usar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este "*LookAndFeel*" é o Nimbus, que o netbeans configura automaticamente quando você está usando a ferramenta de criação gráfica que ele possui. Para mudar o LAF(LookAndFeel), basta ir no código do `main`, e achar este trecho aqui:

```
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Alterando a linha do if para:

```
if ("Windows".equals(info.getName()))
```

ou até mesmo

```
if ("Windows Classic".equals(info.getName()))
```

O primeiro estilo vai tentar adaptar a aparência para versão atual do windows que está executando a aplicação, a segunda vai tentar adaptar para uma versão classica, parecida com o windows 98.

É possivel remover aquele laço `for` dentro do `try/catch`, e fazer a chamada abaixo, que vai invocar o tema do sistema usado atualmente:

```
try {
    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Lembrando que, se rodar sua aplicação em algum SO diferente do windows, o java irá mudar para o tema "Metal", que é o unico tema "Cross plataform" que vem embutido no JDK. Para ter a aparência de windows, independente do sistema, talvez seja necessário [criar um LAF próprio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

[**Neste link**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) há unama lista de outros LAF's existentes no java-swing.

Comment: Show de bola, muito bem explicado. Irei testar e te repondo. Vlw

Comment: @RodrigoStortideOliveira se a resposta lhe servir, não se esqueça de marca-la como aceita, para que sirva de referencia para outros usuarios :)